# Does Acts 2:7 suggest that all of the 120 of Pentecost were part of the lost sheep of the northern kingdom of Israel?

Tags: matthew, acts

[Galilee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilee) was "the northern kingdom" of Israel though that kingdom was no longer God's people. The scattered sheep were referred to as "the lost sheep of the house of Israel" aka "Ephraim".

> [Acts 2:7 NASB] (7) They were amazed and astonished, saying, "Why, **are not all these who are speaking Galileans?**

For more background please see [my related answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28597/in-acts-26-does-%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%E1%BF%B6%CE%BD-refer-to-the-disciples-or-to-the-hearers/41570?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C68.0796#41570).

Jesus said that he was sent only for the lost sheep of the house of Israel:

> [Mat 15:24 ASV] (24) But he answered and said, **I was not sent but unto the lost sheep of the house of Israel.**
>
> [Mat 10:5-6 ASV] (5) These twelve Jesus sent forth, and charged them, saying, **Go not into any way of the Gentiles, and enter not into any city of the Samaritans: (6) but go rather to the lost sheep of the house of Israel.**

The angel even refers to the disciples aka apostles as "You men from Galilee":

> [Acts 1:11 CSB] (11) They said, **"Men of Galilee**, why do you stand looking up into heaven? This same Jesus, who has been taken from you into heaven, will come in the same way that you have seen him going into heaven."

For more background on the **centrality** of the recovery of the lost sheep to the theology of the NT [I strongly recommend this video](https://youtu.be/aeQr1tD1rtI?t=450). I have it cued up to the meat and you can stop half way because after that it gets off base as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: One time I played with the concept of sheep as the metaphor for words, was interesting that day.

Comment: http://img.picturequotes.com/2/441/440937/sometimes-a-cigar-is-just-a-smoke-and-a-storys-just-a-story-quote-1.jpg   :)   What makes you think the scriptures are actually a code book?

Comment: Because psychology is the study of the soul. Ref: Ephesians 4:30, and Denial of the comparison of the occurrence and the plan causes the change in Spirit, but Acceptance that is Faith will stop the weeping and gnashing of teeth, and undo the fruits of the realization of function and error that is why. Therefore stopping the decay of the body and making us life forever so Ref: John 3:16

Comment: When you say "Ref: Ephesians 4:30", do you mean in English or in Jungian imagery?

Comment: I say when they ate the fruits it woke up the Anterior Cingulate Cortex, but faith overcomes the response of the Amygdala maintaining the Spirit required by God. In the simpler way of saying it, your acceptance will overcome denial and saying it through religious terminology your faith will overcome sin.

Comment: In language, the words are indeed symbols but the agreed upon symbols. Who agrees with your enormous lexicon of biblical symbols so they can understand what you are on about?

Comment: Let us talk here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96468/biblical-symbols

Answer (score 1):

Considering the migration of the Jews in 700 years after the fall of Samaria, as well as the conquer of Galilee by the Maccabean dynasty, it is impossible to claim all the Galileans belongs to the people of northern kingdom of Israel.

Furthermore, the house of Israel usually refer to all descendants of Jacob, and not to the northern tribes alone. At least, two of Jesus disciples were not from Galilee. They were Judas Iscariot who betray Jesus, and Iscariot is usually thought to be a Greek rendering of the Hebrew phrase איש־קריות, (Îš-Qrîyôt), meaning "the man from Kerioth" (reference from Wikipedia), and Matthew (Levi). So not all 120 in Pentecost were from the northern tribes.
[image]

Comment: Also some of the 120 were from Bethany and Jerusalem.